# Pandas concat with different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs that I want to concat

(sorry I don't know how to properly recreate a df here)

```
A  B
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3

A  C
a1 c1
a4 c4
```

Result:

```
A  B C
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 NaN
a3 b3 NaN
a4 NaN c4
```

I have tried:

```
merge = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis = 0,ignore_index= True)
```

but this seems to just append the second df to the first df

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need an `outer` join:

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df2,how='outer')

    A    B    C
0  a1   b1   c1
1  a2   b2  NaN
2  a3   b3  NaN
3  a4  NaN   c4
```